# I am getting key error when trying to access flask session data from another handler function

Tags: python, flask, flask-session

I am using dialogflow fulfillment flask package to build a simple chatbot. When I try to access the session variable in the **def goalName(agent)** handler that I set previously in the **get_Name_ID(agent)** handler, I get a key error message from the Heroku logs.

here is the webhook I am using:

```
@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def webhook() -> Dict:
  
    """Handle webhook requests from Dialogflow."""
    # Get WebhookRequest object
    request_ = request.get_json(force=True)

    # Log request headers and body
    logger.info(f'Request headers: {dict(request.headers)}')
    logger.info(f'Request body: {request_}')

    # Handle request
    agent = WebhookClient(request_)

    action = request_.get('queryResult').get('action')

    if action  == "get.secret.key":
        agent.handle_request(get_Name_ID)

    if action  == "goal.setting.name":
        agent.handle_request(goalName)
```

here is the first handler function

```
def get_Name_ID(agent):

    task = TASK.query.filter_by(status="active").first()

    if not USER.query.filter_by(passcode = agent.parameters["id"]).first():
        user = USER(agent.parameters["id"], agent.parameters["name"])
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()


    # store variables into session for later usage
    key = id_generator()
    user_session = SESSION(task.id, key)
    db.session.add(user_session)
    db.session.flush()

    # store values to session
    session['s_id'] = user_session.id
    session['u_id'] = agent.parameters["id"]
    session['user_name'] = agent.parameters["name"]

    db.session.commit()
```

here is the second handler function:

```
def goalName(agent):
   
    task = TASK.query.filter_by(status="active").first()
    # print(type(redish.get('u_id')))
    # print(redish.get('u_id'))

    # get values from session
    uid  = session['u_id']
    sid  = session['s_id']

    goal = GOAL(uid, task.id, sid, agent.parameters["goalName"], "", "", "", "", "")
    db.session.add(goal)
    db.session.flush()
    session['goal_id'] = goal.id
    db.session.commit()
```

I have setup the flask-session in the following manner:

```
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY') or \
    'e5ac358c-f0bf-11e5-9e39-d3b532c10a28'

app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'sqlalchemy'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

app.config['SESSION_SQLALCHEMY'] = db

sess = Session(app)
```

I have tried the following methods:

1. removing the flask-session package and using built-in flask session but with no success.
2. I have set up simple routes to test the session and it was working fine. But it fails to work within the handler functions.

I am getting the key error when accessing session data from the second handler:

_ 2021-08-05T10:47:48.928371+00:00 app[web.1]: return super().**getitem**(key) 2021-08-05T10:47:48.928372+00:00 app[web.1]: KeyError: 'u_id

I am not sure what is going on? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use redis server for session. It Will be solved your issue

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Yes, you are right. I came to the conclusion that the problems are being caused by the fact that webhook requests are independent of user requests.  Because users did not interact with the app directly when the session was created, this could be the culprit. I recently decided to use Redis session store to serve the purpose.